# return array of string from optional array

Tags: javascript

there is optional array inside an array, which have object key as a string, I want to return all the strings in new array.

```
 this.arr =   [
      {
        text: "some text",
        numberValue: 560,
        booleanValue: true,
        arrayValue: [
          {
            text: "I am some text",
            numberValue: 13,
            booleanValue: false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: "some",
        numberValue: 0,
        booleanValue: true,
        arrayValue: [
          {
            text: "I some text",
            numberValue: 12333,
            booleanValue: true
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: "someddkjd",
        numberValue: 0,
        booleanValue: true
      },
      {
        text: "someckckk",
        numberValue: 0,
        booleanValue: true,
        arrayValue: [
          {
            text: "Ime text",
            numberValue: 12333,
            booleanValue: true
          }
        ]
      }
]
```

I want to return an string array  which targets the string property of arrayValue
The result which I want is

```
newArray = ["Iam some text", "I some text", "Ime text"];
```

what I tried is

```
 for(let i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++){
  this.stringArr.push(this.arr[i].arrayValue[i].text);
  }
```

Some additional points to the question:-
arrayValue is optional, it can be there or not, like if see object number3 there is no arrayValue.
 Also, there can be multiple objects inside the  arrayValue

Comment: Since there is only 1 object in `arrayValue`, so you will need `arrayValue[0]` instead of `arrayValue[i]`

Comment: There can be more than one object in arrayValue. How can I solve this. The data is hardcoded what I will get in actual would be dynamic

Comment: for(let i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++){
for( var j=0;j<this.arr[i].arrayValue.length;j++){
  this.stringArr.push(this.arr[i].arrayValue[j].text);
  }
}
try this...

Comment: You need second foreach for arrayValue and use new constant in it. 'this.stringArr.push(this.arr[i].arrayValue[j].text)'

Comment: did you try nested loop in your case when more than one object in arrayValue

Comment: @Developer I've done it using reduce/map also considered the possibility of multiple objects in `arrayValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there can be **many** objects in the `arrayValue` array, then you can use **[`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** to get the strings out of it. If the `arrayValue` property is not present we can filter the undefined values out by **[`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**.

```js
const arr =  [{"text":"some text","numberValue":560,"booleanValue":true,"arrayValue":[{"text":"I am some text","numberValue":13,"booleanValue":false}]},{"text":"some","numberValue":0,"booleanValue":true,"arrayValue":[{"text":"I some text","numberValue":12333,"booleanValue":true}]},{"text":"someddkjd","numberValue":0,"booleanValue":true},{"text":"someckckk","numberValue":0,"booleanValue":true,"arrayValue":[{"text":"Ime text","numberValue":12333,"booleanValue":true}]}];
const newArray = arr.map(obj => obj.arrayValue && Array.isArray(obj.arrayValue) ? obj.arrayValue.map(ele => ele.text).join("") : undefined).filter(obj => obj);
console.log(newArray);
```

We can do the same using **[`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)**, in the logic I have first checked if the property exists then secondly checked if it is indeed an array by doing `Array.isArray` if yes then `joined` on all the `text` properties of the objects in `arrayValue`:

```js
const arr =  [{"text":"some text","numberValue":560,"booleanValue":true,"arrayValue":[{"text":"I am some text","numberValue":13,"booleanValue":false}]},{"text":"some","numberValue":0,"booleanValue":true,"arrayValue":[{"text":"I some text","numberValue":12333,"booleanValue":true}]},{"text":"someddkjd","numberValue":0,"booleanValue":true},{"text":"someckckk","numberValue":0,"booleanValue":true,"arrayValue":[{"text":"Ime text","numberValue":12333,"booleanValue":true}]}];
const newArray = arr.reduce((acc, ele) => ele.arrayValue && Array.isArray(ele.arrayValue) ? acc.concat(ele.arrayValue.map(ele => ele.text).join("")) : acc, []);
console.log(newArray);
```

I've used the **[`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** to concatenate the text properties of inner `arrayValue` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like

```
this.stringArr = [];
for(let item of this.arr){
  for(let item2 of item.arrayValue){
    this.stringArr.push(item2.text);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple **[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** and **[`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)** like this:

```js
const arr = [{text:"some text",numberValue:560,booleanValue:true,arrayValue:[{text:"I am some text",numberValue:13,booleanValue:false}]},{text:"some",numberValue:0,booleanValue:true,arrayValue:[{text:"I some text",numberValue:12333,booleanValue:true}]},{text:"someddkjd",numberValue:0,booleanValue:true},{text:"someckckk",numberValue:0,booleanValue:true,arrayValue:[{text:"Ime text",numberValue:12333,booleanValue:true}]}]

const texts = arr.reduce((r, { arrayValue }) => 
  arrayValue ? r.concat(arrayValue.map(a => a.text)) : r
, [])

console.log(texts)
```

Comment: Can you explain how you did it?. I am trying understand the concept but confused

Comment: Loop through the array using `reduce`. Then [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the `arrayValue` in the parameter. if `arrayValue` has value, then get all the texts using `arrayValue.map(a => a.text)` and concat it to the accumulator `r`. Else return the accumulator. You can go through the links in the anwer to know more about reduce